# How to make a view become transparent to uncover background content?

Tags: ios, swift, view, transparent

I have set an image in background using this code:

```
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image1")!)
```

However, I have some contentView on top, and I am trying to have those transparent to unveil the background.

How can this be done ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `alpha`

```
self.contentView.alpha = 0.1
```

If `alpha = 1.0` then the view is opaque, you can also set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

for that view do the following :

thatView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: thanks. But I tried, and it doesnt work. there is still a white "banner like" on top of the background image

Comment: Black means it's transparant now, but also means your image hasn't been properly loaded. Have you added it the file to your project ? Included in your target ? Is the view correctly set ?...